# Search a specific file in Gnome file manager

Tags: gnome, nautilus, filemanager, xdotool

This script is executed by home automation assistant in Linux 14.04, Gnome-desktop

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-open /home/Folder && xdotool search Folder | head -n 1 | tail -n 1 | VAR1=%1 | xdotool windowfocus window=$VAR1 && sleep 1 && xdotool key Down && xdotool key ctrl+f && xdotool type Under
```

It is useful to search the string Under in the /home/Folder. I would like to search exclusively for all the video types, using the terminal and adding a command to the list above.
Can you help me?
Thanks.